# manage a system of Ubuntu computers from a single computer

Tags: edubuntu

I'm a student at a small high school in Denmark, im the only one using Ubuntu, but I'd like the other students to at least try it.

So I asked for permission to set up a small group of computers for the others to try, mostly for smaller school tasks, or random internet surfing.

So far they've let me set up 4 computers, and I would like to manage all the computers from a single computer which should also work as the "picture" for the other computers.

i need software to manage this, as mentioned below is VNC as an opportunity, but what i get from reading about it is that this kind of soft ware is just sharing a screen (which is hopefully wrong)

and what equipment would I like to use?

Comment: This is a really interesting question, but I think it would be worth changing the title to reflect it more accurately. I'm sure there are plenty of people who'd be interested in what you're asking about but won't realise it's here since it's been mis-titled.

Comment: i believe you are right, but i can't come up with a good title

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you mean by synchronise?

Comment: The Landscape service is for this.  You can tell each installation to install security updates automatically, and then ssh in manually to update packages as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clonezilla is used for replicating or imaging installations to multiple machine, and not for synchronizing or managing. If you want to manage or control multiple machines from a single machine, then you can use remote desktop tools like VNC or, if you prefer command line, you can use ssh. Read the section on [remote access here](http://ubuntuguide.org/wiki/Ubuntu%3aKarmic#Remote_Access). As for your question "What is an Ubuntu server?", you can read here: [Ubuntu Server Edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/server)

Comment: i've been reading a bit on different VNC clients (programmes, im sorry for my bad english expressions :-P) and what i get is that i can have different computers showing the same on all screens, but then i think that when i move the mouse on the first computer i'll move it on other computers as well? or am i getting something wrong?

Comment: i was going to use ssh, but since its only 4 computers the teachers wouldn't give me static IP's so i have to manage them from their own screens... *sigh* its probably much easier to do it their way as well, but not as fun :-(

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider trialling [Landscape](http://landscape.canonical.com) which has a systems management interface to manage multiple desktop Ubuntu installations. It's a pay-for service, but you can register for a free trial to see if it fits your requirements.